# Google pre-rendering causing double and triple events

Tags: php, javascript, tracking, google-chrome, laravel

Is it possible to detect google chrome and firefox prerendering on the server side, or in .htaccess, and defer the prerendering for the purpose of monitoring traffic and website events, or do I need to move my website event tracking into javascript. =/

I am using laravel and angular js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems as though different browsers will act differently.

- Firefox: Will send the header `X-moz: prefetch` whenever a page is "pre-fetched."
- Chrome: You're out of luck, simply because it forces you to use the Page Visibility API, which is JS-based. The term "pre-rendering" applies exclusively to Chrome, as Google seem to be doing their own thing on this one.

Comment: So it looks like I will have to replace my event tracking solutions with something ajax based. Not something I wanted to do, but my hands seem to be tied at this point.